# Something odd with traffic numbers on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, traffic

Take a look at https://stackexchange.com/sites, does every user in stackoverflow.com visit the site 3 times a day? Or is the anonymous traffic just huge? (for every site in stackexchange.com, by the way)

Comment: I visit the site *at least* 3 times a day on a lot of days. I suspect I'm not alone in that. Plus all of the anonymous traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most larger SE sites, more than 90% of traffic is from search engines, those users usually don't have an account on the SE site. I don't see anything unusal with these statistics.